# c# Generic Repository class

Tags: c#, repository

I have various repository clases that have a DeleteEntity method like this:

```
public void DeleteEntity(int Key)
    {
        try
        {
            ObjectParameter error = new ObjectParameter("Error", typeof(string));
            context.proc_BorrarChofer(Key, error);                
            if (error.Value.ToString() != "")
            {
                Errores myerror = new Errores();
                myerror.ID = 100;
                myerror.Descripcion = error.Value.ToString();
                MyErrors.Add(myerror);
            }
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            // Update the values of the entity that failed to save from the store 
            ex.Entries.Single().Reload();
            // status = ex.Message; 
            Errores myerror = new Errores();
            myerror.ID = 1000;
            myerror.Descripcion = ex.Message.ToString();
            MyErrors.Add(myerror);

        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            string status = (ex.InnerException.InnerException != null) ? ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message : "";
            Errores myerror = new Errores();
            myerror.ID = 1000;
            myerror.Descripcion = status;
            MyErrors.Add(myerror);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //paso los errores
            Errores myerror = new Errores();
            myerror.ID = 1000;
            myerror.Descripcion = ex.Message.ToString();
            MyErrors.Add(myerror);
        }
```

Now every Repository class have the same method. Only the name of the Stored Procedure change. How Can I make a Generic Delete method and pass as parameter sp Name?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you mean that this line `context.proc_BorrarChofer(Key, error); ` changes in repositories ?

Comment: Exactly. Every repository must call a diferent sp to delete an entity. The rest is exactly the same for all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your place i would remake this code with using of template design pattern

```
public abstract class BaseRepository
{
  protected abstract void DeleteEntityWithProcedure(int key, ObjectParameter error);

  public void DeleteEntity(int Key)
  {
    try
    {
        ObjectParameter error = new ObjectParameter("Error", typeof(string));
        DeleteEntityWithProcedure(key, error);
        if (error.Value.ToString() != "")
        {
            Errores myerror = new Errores();
            myerror.ID = 100;
            myerror.Descripcion = error.Value.ToString();
            MyErrors.Add(myerror);
        }
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        // Update the values of the entity that failed to save from the store 
        ex.Entries.Single().Reload();
        // status = ex.Message; 
        Errores myerror = new Errores();
        myerror.ID = 1000;
        myerror.Descripcion = ex.Message.ToString();
        MyErrors.Add(myerror);

    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        string status = (ex.InnerException.InnerException != null) ? ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message : "";
        Errores myerror = new Errores();
        myerror.ID = 1000;
        myerror.Descripcion = status;
        MyErrors.Add(myerror);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //paso los errores
        Errores myerror = new Errores();
        myerror.ID = 1000;
        myerror.Descripcion = ex.Message.ToString();
        MyErrors.Add(myerror);
    }
}
```

Your concrete repositories will be like this

```
public class CustomerRepository:BaseRepository
{
   protected override DeleteEntityWithProcedure(int key, ObjectParameter error)
    {
      //execute procedure you needed
      //context.proc_BorrarChofer(Key, error); 
    }
}
```

Execute your custom repository

```
var customerRepository = new CustomerRepository();
customerRepository.DeleteEntity(1);
```

Comment: Great Idea! Thanks! but shouldn't "error" parameter by passed by ref to DeleteEntityWithProcedure?

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer works just fine. I would do it following the Adapter Design Pattern. This one allows us to centralize your efforts and will allow you create different implementations without affecting your front end implementation. This pattern is helpful here because we convert an interface that is available into an interface that is needed.

First we create our Interface

```
public interface IEntity
{
    void DeleteEntity(int key, Error error);
}
```

Then we create as many repositories as needed. For example: ChoferRepository or otroRepository:

```
public class ChoferRepository: IEntity
{
    public void DeleteEntity(int key, Error error)
    {
        // todo: Add your custom code here. 
        // You coul implement not only any store procedure but any data source
    }
}

public class OtroRepository: IEntity
{
    public void DeleteEntity(int key, Error error)
    {
        // todo: Add your custom code here. 
        // You coul implement not only any store procedure but any data source
    }
}
```

Last is our implementation.

```
/// <summary>
/// This is just an example on how to implement your generic approach using the adapter pattern
/// </summary>
public class WebClient
{
    IEntity ChoferEntity { get; set; }
    IEntity OtraEntity { get; set; }

    public WebClient()
    {
        //You can use as many repositories as you want knowing they all could have different data sources or different store procedures inside same data source
        ChoferEntity.DeleteEntity(1, new Error());

        OtraEntity.DeleteEntity(1, new Error());
    }
}
```

Comment: It's good idea if he had different implementations of out repositories and we do not want to change our client code if we switch repositories. But topic author sad that issue is code duplication(all `Delete` methods are almost the same) and he wanted to make code more generic.Personally i don't see how this can help to resolve this

Comment: One of the advantages of using this approach is that the client does not care about how entities are deleted. We could have the same methods such as to delete entity. Here the adapter takes the responsibility to pass or take some or all the operation. In my opinion we should not decide what datasource or store procedure to use inside the repository. This approach provides a good alternative for when upgrading interdependent components. For example when changing to another store procedure or adding any other change.